# How can I implement many `description` methods easily?

Tags: swift, swift4

I have many structures I defined.
And now, I'm implementing many `description` methods. 
Do you know more easy way?

```
public struct Button: Codable, Dictionable {
    public var  type: String?
    public var  title: String?
    public var  value: String?
}
extension Button: CustomStringConvertible, CustomDebugStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        return "type: \(type ?? ""), title: \(title ?? ""), value: \(value ?? "")"
    }
    public var debugDescription: String {
        return description
    }
}
```

Comment: An easier way is to declare the struct members non-optional as much as possible. Declaring variables optional as a *don't care* alibi is bad habit. Consider that any non-optional will never crash the app

Comment: Why would you define a description for every type?

Comment: @vadian Thank you. You are right. Sorry for the bad example, this is JSON Strings returned from the server. I thought `optional` is safety.

Comment: @Sulthan Hmm ... I thought default console logs were complex. I wanted to see only values simply.

Comment: @MaikoOhkawa Is your every struct is `Codable`?

Comment: Yes, All structures are `Codable`. I use `JSONDecoder` for converting.

Comment: Then why don't you return json string from the `description` method that will help you in debugging.

Comment: Hmm, thank you, I try it.